# Reference to exe in a .Net 4.6.1 project

Tags: c#, .net, dll, exe, .net-4.6.1

I need to make API calls to methods in an EXE provided by a software company. In the past very old .Net version, I was able to make it work by renaming the exe to dll (I guess?). This time around the EXE they have provided seems to have been compiled in 4.6.1. I am not able to make it work and it causes runtime errors:
"Could not load file or assembly... A strongly-named assembly is required"

What are my options? Is it still possible to make API calls to an EXE whether or not I rename it to a DLL? Or Should I ask them to provide me a proper DLL?

Thank you.

Comment: If it is signed (strongly-named) .exe it will not work, when you renamed it. Anyway, as far as I know, you don't need to rename .exe to .dll to load it (if you are sure, that this .exe is managed)

Comment: Thanks vasily. I hope it is not a typo. Please clarify: "If it is signed ... it will not work". Did you mean to say, "it will work"?

Comment: If it signed **and** renamed, it will not work, because a name of file is a part of strong assembly name.

Comment: No, it is not renamed. To be honest, I am not even sure if it was already signed. I thought it should be signed by the software provider. Anyway, I tried signing it at my end with the best available certificate. Still causing same runtime errors.

Comment: ok, wait, this is a little misleading. 1st: you don't need to rename anything to load it as .net assembly regardless of whether it is _.exe_, _.dll_, or _.txt_. As long as there is a **managed code** inside - everything should work. 2nd: I think/believe, that as name of file is included in assembly strong name - changing it will broke assembly loading eventually. 3rd: If assembly is signed - you can't (without disassembling) sign it with your key/certificate, and you don't need to do this in most cases.

Comment: also, sometimes .exe is packed with some sort of packers. In this case you probably need to unpack it before loading.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, what you are saying is that the assembly needs to be strong-named signed by the developers, since they have the source code, and not by me. Is this correct?

Comment: No, not-strong-named (not signed) assembly **may be** strong-named by developer or anyone else, but most of the time developers doesn't signing (strong-naming) their assemblies. But if they do strong-named their assembly - it is hard to "re-strong-name" them.

Comment: I don't understand, why would someone down-vote my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @vasily.sib and the following link, I was able to resolve this issue.

I can in fact reference any EXE assembly in the project and call methods on it. An EXE (and for that matter a DLL) can be strong named and signed by anyone, and not just by the developer who has the source code for that EXE. See the following link for details.

Thank you.

https://chrisbenard.net/2009/07/16/strong-name-an-assembly-without-source-code/